# Can I share my CSS with another application when using asset pipeline?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I am using Rails asset pipeline in a rails 4.x web app.  In production I use a CDN (cloudfront) to serve the CSS.

My other application is a non-rails app, but it shares the same CSS as my Rails app.

Is there a way for my other application to use the CSS generated by my rails application?

The problem I am having is that since rails generates a random guid for the filename there is no way for me to reference it in  my other application.

e.g.

```
https://abcd.cloudfront.net/assets/application-asdf23409usdflu34uasdf.css
```

**Update**

If I can get the value I can potentially expose the CSS URL as an API endpoint, is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

When you deploying your application and precompiling assets, the task also generates a manifest-md5hash.json that contains a list with all your assets and their respective fingerprints. It looks like:

```
{"files":{"application-723d1be6cc741a3aabb1cec24276d681.js":{"logical_path":"application.js","mtime":"2013-07-26T22:55:03-07:00","size":302506, "digest":"723d1be6cc741a3aabb1cec24276d681"}, etc...}
```

You can transfer this file to another application and get correct filenames with guids from it.

Comment: Can I just get the value someshow to expose as an API endpoint?

Comment: Rails.application.assets['your_assets_file_name.css'].digest or .digest_path for full assets file name